# find: chown: Argument list too long

Tags: shell

I am trying to change the permissions on all files with group or owner 1001 to 1000.

I've tested these 2 commands on a small directory and they both work, but when I try using them all the way from root, I get the 'argument list too long' error

```
find /share/CACHEDEV2_DATA/Container -user 1001 -exec chown 1000 {} +
find /share/CACHEDEV2_DATA/Container -group 1001 -exec chgrp 1000 {} +
```

Is there a different way I can execute the command to get around this error?

Comment: @Ethanopp : The `+` in your `find` is killing you. Either follow the approach suggested by Mark Setchell, or let `find` just print the file names and pipe it into `xargs` for changing ownership, or don't use the `+`, but `\;` instead. With the huge number of files, the latter might take very long, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with **GNU Parallel** quite simply and efficiently if you use the `-X` option which passes as many arguments as your system's `ARGMAX` allows.

I am not at a machine to  check this, so try it on a small directory with a copy of just a few files before you let rip through a whole filesystem:

```
find <STARTDIRECTORY> -user 1001 -print0 | parallel --dry-run -X -0 chown 1000 {}
```

If that looks correct, run it again but omitting the `--dry-run`.

Comment: To the down-voter... whilst everyone with sufficient reputation, is obviously at liberty to down-vote, it would be courteous, to at least say what is incorrect/objectionable about the answer so that we can all learn from your knowledge/experience. If you just think other answers are better, then just vote for them and mine will naturally sink to the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot talk on behalf of the down-voter. It might be that the parallel solution is not effective when the amount of processing (`chown`) for each file is minimal. 99% of the cost is forking/exec the sub shell, and running it in parallel is unlikely to yield any improvement vs. sequential processing `chown ... file1 file2 file3 ...`

Comment: @dash-o Do you have any tests to backup that claim? These days I am surprised how many tasks that benefit from being parallelized. Given the path name in the question, it is likely that we are talking about a network file system, and in my experience they can behave rather different from a local file system. See also https://oletange.wordpress.com/2019/04/10/parallelization-is-it-faster/ and https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/

Comment: For obvious reason, we are not going to benchmark this over multiple OS, file systems, etc. On my system `chown` for 100 files take 0.002 seconds when batching to a single call, and 0.1s when each file is running in separate chwon. It will need at least 50X just to match the performance, not accounting for extra CPU needed to launch all those processes. I can not comment on other configurations.

Comment: @dash-o Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I doubt the down-vote resulted from any benchmarking - and in any case, the OP's question was not about performance but just getting a job done without *"Argument list too long"* errors. Given that ARGMAX is 200,000 (on my system at least) and guessing a filename might typically average 100 characters, **GNU Parallel** is only going to spawn one new `chown` process for every 2,000 files so the cost of the new process will be amortised over many, many files.

Comment: @dash-o Also, if it is a high-latency network filesystem, there could be a significant benefit to having 4/8/16 processes running in parallel because most of the time will be spent waiting for a reply and you may as well wait for 16 replies in parallel because waiting for replies doesn't consume much CPU or network bandwith.

Comment: @dash-o I note someone has also down-voted your answer, so let's just not worry about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Short version:

Given number of files, placing all arguments on a single command will fail (too many arguments, or too long command line). Using xargs to batch lines will solve the line length problem, and improve the performance.

```
# Preferred - using NUL to separate files
find /share/CACHEDEV2_DATA/Container -user 1001 -print0 | xargs -0 -L50 chown 1000

# Without protection against "special" file names (risky)
find /share/CACHEDEV2_DATA/Container -user 1001 | xargs -L50 chown 1000
```

Long Answer:

As indicated by some commentors, the source of the problem is the trailing '+' (instead of the more commonly used trailing ';') to the find command. From `info find`

> ... The SVR4 edition of Unix introduced a slight variation, which involves
>   terminating the command with '+' instead:
>
> ```
>  find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -exec /bin/rm {} \+
> ```
>
> The above use of '-exec' causes 'find' to build up a long command
>   line and then issue it. ...

So find offers two bulking options - one file per line, and ALL files per line.

Clearly, this is a case to integrate with 'xargs', which provide more flexible way to batch lines - by argument count (-L...) or line size (-s). Also, should consider using the null terminator to support situation where file names have spaces, magic characters ('*'), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
chown -R john:build /tmp/src
```